# Copy column data consisting of blank cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am into a situation where I need to copy a range from a excel sheet and paste it to another. I have done the following coding which is going well...

```
Dim mpn As String

mpn = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Input the MPN column name:")

mpn1 = mpn

mpn2 = mpn1 & ":" & mpn

Set currentSheet = wbSource.Worksheets(1)

lastRow1 = currentSheet.Range(mpn1).End(xlDown).Row

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F2:F" & lastRow1) = currentSheet.Range(mpn2 & lastRow1).Value
```

This coding goes perfectly well untill there is any blank cell in the column. Can anyone please help me on this particular situation.

Comment: `This coding goes perfectly well untill there is any blank cell in the column` And hence you should never use `xldown` to get the last cell with data :) Use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: Also instead of prompting for the column name, use `.Find` to locate the column name. What if user types `Blah Blah` in the input box? See[this](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) on how to use `.Find`

Comment: @SiddharthRout thanks for the so prompt reply boss...but I got an error in this line lastRow1 = currentSheet.Range(mpn1 & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Try this `lastRow1 = currentSheet.Range(mpn1 & currentSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` I am also assuming that `mpn1` is a valid column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments above, instead of prompting for the column name, use `.Find` to locate the column name. What if user types Blah Blah in the input box?

Also as mentioned in comments use `xlUp` rather than `xlDown` to find the last row to counter for blank cells and other issues you may face. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Is this what you are trying? (**Untested**)

I have commented the code so you should not having a problem understanding it. But if you do then simply post back :)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim mpnCol As Long
    Dim ColName As String, strSearch As String
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wbInput As Worksheet, currentSheet As Worksheet

    '~~> Change this to the Mpn Header
    strSearch = "MPN"

    '~~> This you have declared in your code
    '~~> Change as applicable
    Set wbSource = "Someworkbook"

    Set currentSheet = wbSource.Worksheets(1)
    Set wbInput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    With currentSheet
        '~~> Search for the mpn header in row 1. Change as applicable
        Set aCell = .Rows(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            '~~> Column Number
            mpnCol = aCell.Column
            '~~> Converting column number to column name
            ColName = Split(.Cells(, mpnCol).Address, "$")(1)
            '~~> Getting last row
            lRow = .Range(ColName & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            '~~> Checking for excel versions. Comment this if the copying
            '~~> will always happen in xl2007+ versions
            If lRow > 65536 Then
                MsgBox "Are you trying to copy from xl2007 to xl2003?. The number of rows exceed the row limit"
                Exit Sub
            End If

            wbInput.Range("F2:F" & lRow).Value = .Range(ColName & "2:" & ColName & lRow).Value
        Else
            MsgBox strSearch & " header not found"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice comprehensive response - covers a lot more than the single issue OP has found so far. I can see him revisiting this as he learns more, and encounters further issues.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier: `I can see him revisiting this...` Me too :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout and richard you guys have lots more knowledge on this thread and am trying those in my code too...

Comment: @SiddharthRout am getting this error "Method Range Failed in _worksheet failed" in this line currentSheet.Range(mpn1 & currentSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: What is `mpn1`? I never suggested that in the code above? :)

Comment: `mpn1` in the code is the column name input by the user.

Answer (score 1):

To copy an **entire column**, reference your range with the `.Columns()` function.

You could use something like:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("F") = 
    currentSheet.Columns(mpn1).Value
```

---

Another alternative would be to use the `.Copy` sub and specify a `Destination` for the copy:

```
currentSheet.Columns(mpn1).Copy 
    Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("F")
Application.CutCopyMode = false
```

---

This answer assumes both workbooks are saved with the same version of Excel. If one workbook is pre-2007, and one is 2007+, then the max number of rows allowed in a sheet will be different.

In that case, copying the entire column is not an option - check out [Siddarth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26796587/383414) for a longer solution to that extra complication. He checks for different number of rows to prevent the error.

Comment: This may give you an error if you are copying from xl2007+ to xl2003 :)

Comment: I have shown what I was talking about in the answer that I have posted above :)

Comment: + 1 now it makes sense :)